# how to convert this string '2014-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00' into date in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

i have my date coming in string form :'2014-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00'
how can TO  convert this into date format in informaticA

Comment: This is also known as a - "full", "round trip" - [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date-time with timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a sub string of the time string '2014-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00' to '2014-12-31' after all you need date part only.

Then parse the date using to_date method.

```
to_date('substring date','yyyy-dd-mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
to_date('2014-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD.HH:MI:SS.MS......')
```

Keep in mind that it ignores the time zone information.